# How to calculate it without l'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate this limit without using l'Hopital rule?
$$\lim_{x\to 1 }\frac{3^{5x}-3^{2x^2+3}}{\sin(\pi x)}$$
I know how to make it using L'Hopital and that the result is $-\frac{243\log(3)}{\pi}$, but I'm getting nowhere when I try without it. Any advice? I also tried to change ${\sin(\pi x)}$ to ${\tan x}*{\cos x}$, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more context.  Where does this limit come from?  Why are you interested in it?  Aside from l'Hospital's rule, what theorems, definitions, or results do you know?  At the very least, what have you tried to do, and where did it go wrong?  For more information, please see the [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) post on the meta site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Set $x-1=h$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{3^{5+5h}-3^{2(h+1)^2+3}}{\sin\pi(1+h)}$$

$$=-\dfrac{5\cdot3^5\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{3^{5h}-1}{5h}-3^5\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{3^{2h^2+4h}-1}{2h^2+4h}\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{2h^2+4h}h}{\pi\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin\pi h}{\pi h}}$$

Now use for  $a>0,$ $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{a^h-1}h=\ln a$$